# Add dynamic date format to Momen.js in Vue

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I need to display the date format depending on saved settings. I call axios to check saved date format:

```
 axios
     .get('/api/user/')
     .then(response => (this.date_format = response.data.dateformat))
```

Then I added filters:

```
        filters: {
        moment: function (date) {
          return moment(date).format(this.date_format);
        }
      },
```

And display it in HTML:

```
<p class="card-title"> Date of Birth:
   <span[[dob | moment]]</span>
</p>
```

If I display [[data_format]] it shows correctly **"DD/MM/YYYY"**. But when I try to console.log(this.date_format) console shows **Undefined**.
How to replace **FormatNeeded** in **return moment(date).format(FormatNeeded);** with **this.date_format**?

Comment: It isn't a simple typo of `date_format` (code block) vs `data_format` (console.log in last paragraph), is it?

Comment: yes, sorry it was just a typo in the question - edited.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out how to solve the problem. When I call API, I set **date_format** to a global variable (probably not the correct term):

```
            axios
            .get('/api/user/')
            .then(response => (this.date_format = response.data.dateformat))
            .then(response => (window.date_format = this.date_format))
```

Then in filters, I use **window.date_format** not **this.date_format**:

```
        filters: {
        moment(date) {
            var format_elem = window.date_format;
          return moment(date).format(format_elem);
        }
      }
```